# Walkpat memory test

Tags: c, testing, ram

Does anybody know of any good resources for learning about walkpat memory tests on RAM? If you can provide pseudo or C code that would be even better. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This webpage is quite useful: http://www.ganssle.com/testingram.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile int *ptr;  // volatile because the compiler would otherwise outsmart you and not actually read the memory

for(ptr=0; ptr<SIZE; ptr++) {
    int test = 1;
    do {
        *ptr = test;
        if( *ptr != test ) FAIL();
        test <<= 1;        // walk that 1 through the word, until it falls off the end.
    } while(test);
}
```